# try-with-resource

Tags: java, исключения

у на есть try-with-resource.

Допустим произошло исключение в блоке try и потом исключение при автоматическом закрытии и вызове close().

Правильно ли я понимаю, что исключение в блоке try потеряется и останется только исключение от close()?

Comment: А нет кажется я понял.  Брошенное try-блоком исключение имеет больший приоритет, чем исключения получившиеся во время закрытия. Так ли это?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет исключение в try перекроет исключение в close.
В конструкции try-finally наоборот, исключение из finally перекроет исключение в try.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: да я уже в комментах у себя написал. А еще close() будет подавлено и его можно получить через метод getSuppress.

Comment: @Васька У вас - догадки, у него - факты. Принимайте, если это отвечает на вопрос

Comment: @Miron ну так, то я тоже прочитал javadoc  и спросил да или нет. За час до того как он ответил.